# PHP/MySQL Query not saving data in database

Tags: php

I have this data in a database:

http://pastebin.com/wdgj3aTr

I am able to show plain text using this PHP function:

```
if(!function_exists("dropHtmlTags")) {
    function dropHtmlTags($string) {
        // remove html tags
        $string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t');

        return $string;
    }
}
```

but i want to keep the line breaks when displaying, how can i do this?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
if(!function_exists("dropHtmlTags")) {
    function dropHtmlTags($string) {
        // remove html tags
        $string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t');

        return nl2br($string);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!function_exists("dropHtmlTags")) {
    function dropHtmlTags($string) {
        // remove html tags
        $string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t'); 
        echo nl2br($string);
    }
}
```

Comment: that still displays just one block of text

Comment: `$string = "hi I am pra\nva";
$string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t');
echo nl2br($string);`

Comment: I have just tried that, its working ok but shows /> at the end of each line and line breaks in the wrong place

Comment: Have you tried with nl2br() method? Can you please put your code again!

Comment: `if(!function_exists("dropHtmlTags")) {
    function dropHtmlTags($string) {
        // remove html tags
        $string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t');

        return nl2br($string);
    }
}

echo dropHtmlTags("Hi I am Pra\nva");`
This one works perfectly, I checked just now.

Comment: If the whole html content is your string, then please change the single quote to double quote for `style attribute` for `<v:shape id="Line_x0020_4" ...` and for `<v:shape id="Line_x0020_5"`. I tried and it worked fine.

Comment: For example - From `<v:shape id="Line_x0020_5" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style='position:absolute .....` to `<v:shape id="Line_x0020_5" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute ....`

Comment: it automatically puts the single quotes in because it downloads emails using imap_open in PHP and inserts that data into a database

Comment: you examples above are both the same

Comment: Then please replace your string, before use - 
`str_replace("'", '"', $text);`

Comment: ok, its showing like this Further to my email of yesterday when I advised that Tiffany had left, I have now taken on a new girl (Laura) who is due to start on Monday (2nd June 2014).
 
Please can you set up an email address for her and she will be sitting at Tiffany’s old desk.
  /> Would you also be able to do the name on the phone extension (x209) remotely?
 
Can you also confirm when you have forwarded Tiffany’s old emails to me please and I am
also waiting for a note of her username and password so I can check old emails.
 
Many thanks and I wait to hear from you.
 
Kind Regards />

Comment: Please provide the raw data :) .. not the output

Comment: `if(!function_exists("dropHtmlTags")) {
    function dropHtmlTags($string) {
        // remove html tags
  $string = str_replace("'", '"', $string);
        $string = strip_tags($string, '&nbsp;\r\n\t');

        return nl2br($string);
    }
}

echo dropHtmlTags($string);`- this worked for me. If still not working, then there might be some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stripping the `\n` (new line) replace it with `<br />`

Other possibility, don't strip the `\n` and wrap everything in `<pre></pre>`

Comment: do you have an example please?